# Error on variable passing in Groovy to read JSON array

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins groovy file, I'm reading app name from a JSON file, and if I assign app name manually, value is read, but if I assign a value using variable which does not read and throw errors.

manual app name assigned :

```
${commonConfig.configuration.Cache_list.app_name}".contains("tw")
```

Instead of app_name, how can I assign a variable, I tried following and gave me errors.

```
def app = "app_name"
${commonConfig.configuration.Cache_list.$app}".contains("tw")
```

Sample JSON :

```
 "Cache_list": {"app_name": ["au","sg","tw","jp"],"app2": ["tw","id"]},
```

Comment: Can't understand where is json in your question, but `$` variable accessor inside `${...}` is wrong

Comment: @daggett edited question to add a sample json